# Запуск процедуры обработки при запуске 1с

Tags: 1с

Уже не один день играюсь, но так и не нашел способа запустить заданную процедуру обработки при запуске. Все, что понял за все время, так это то, что функция обработки должна быть экспортной и код для запуска процедуры обработки должен быть в процедуре `ПриНачалеРаботыСистемы`.

Answer (score 1):

Ну да `ПриНачалеРаботыСистемы` приходится прописывать. http://kb.mista.ru/article.php?id=340

Вот решение от Гения1С

```
Если СокрЛП(ПараметрЗапуска)="" Тогда   //параметра нет ничего не делаем 
    ИначеЕсли Лев(ПараметрЗапуска,3)="авт" тогда
        Попытка
            Дл=СтрДлина(ПараметрЗапуска);
            Строка=Прав(ПараметрЗапуска,Дл-3);
            Выполнить(Строка);
        Исключение
            Стр="Не удалось выполнить код:"+Символы.ПС+Строка;
            Предупреждение(Стр,5); Сообщить(Стр);
            ЗавершитьРаботуСистемы();
        КонецПопытки;
КонецЕсли;
```

Запускать с ключом запуска: `/C"АвтВнешняяОбработка = ВнешниеОбработки.Создать(ПолноеИмяФайла); ВнешняяОбработка.Запуститься();"`

Comment: этот способ хороший только если у тебя внешняя обработка, а если обработка встроенная и это надо сделать в веб клиенте?

я попытался таким способом, но к сожалению на веб клиенте говорит что переменная "Обработки" не определена (На Сервере оно не будит бить ошибку но в то же время и сами команды ничего делать не будут)

&НаКлиенте
Процедура ПриНачалеРаботыСистемы()
 
 обр = Обработки.<Обработка>.Создать();
 обр.<Процедура>;

КонецПроцедуры

Comment: а, там "управляемые формы". А если так : ОткрытьФорму("Обработка.<Имяобработки>.Форма.<имямоейуправляемойформы>"); &НаКлиенте естественно. Проверить ,извини,  не могу, не установлена 1С. Но если что гугли - управляемые формы - открыть форму обработки на клиенте

Answer (score 1):

ПриНачалеРаботыСистемы бывает в трёх разных модулях - Управляемого, Обычного приложений и Внешнего соединения. Соответственно, надо определиться - прописан ли вызов нужной процедуры именно в модуле нужного типа приложения.

Под выражением "процедура обработки" что понимается - процедура, которая что-то обрабатывает, или процедура, которая находится в обработке как объекте 1С? Если второе, то где она находится - в модуле обработки, в модуле менеджера или в форме? Ну и главное - обработка внешняя или встроенная в конфигурацию?

Если обработка встроенная и процедура находится в модуле обработки, то код будет такой

```
Обработки.<ИмяОбработки>.Создать().<НазваниеПроцедуры>();
```

Если обработка встроенная и процедура находится в модуле менеджера, то обработку можно не создавать:

```
Обработки.<ИмяОбработки>.<НазваниеПроцедуры>();
```

Если же это веб-клиент, а обработка встроенная, тогда только можно вызвать только процедуру формы обработки.

```
ОткрытьФорму("Обработки.<ИмяОбработки>.<ИмяФормы>");
```

Потому что Обработки не доступны на клиенте, только формы.